# Problems with Nginx 1.18 Reverse Proxy for GRPC Streaming: upstream sent frame for closed stream 1 while reading upstream

Tags: nginx, streaming, grpc, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have created a simple container to upload file using GRPC in .NET. The container works fine on my local machine and remotely, it is proxied by an Nginx server. When the container is deployed, I can smoothly stream the file to the server.
However, when I await for the response:

```
var response = await stream.ResponseAsync;
```

I get the following exception:

> Exception: The HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'INTERNAL_ERROR' (0x2).", DebugException="System.IO.IOException: The request was aborted.
> ---> System.Net.Http.Http2StreamException: The HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'INTERNAL_ERROR' (0x2).
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ThrowRequestAborted(Exception innerException)
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.CheckResponseBodyState()
> at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.TryReadFromBuffer(Span`1 buffer, Boolean partOfSyncRead) at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.ReadDataAsync(Memory`1 buffer, HttpResponseMessage responseMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Grpc.Net.Client.StreamExtensions.ReadMessageAsync[TResponse](Stream responseStream, DefaultDeserializationContext deserializationContext, ILogger logger, Func`2 deserializer, String grpcEncoding, Nullable`1 maximumMessageSize, Dictionary`2 compressionProviders, Boolean singleMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)"))
> ---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. IOException: The request was aborted. Http2StreamException: The HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'INTERNAL_ERROR' (0x2).", DebugException="System.IO.IOException: The request was aborted.

After lots of investigation, it seems there is something wrong with the Nginx reverse proxy. Here is the Nginx setup:

```
server {
   listen      13*.**.**.** ssl http2;
   server_name  mydomain.com 13*.**.**.**;
   access_log   /var/log/nginx/myservice.log;
   error_log    /var/log/nginx/myservice_error.log;
   ssl_certificate  /etc/ssl/certs/myssl.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/myssl.key;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   proxy_buffering off;
   location / {
      grpc_pass         grpcs://127.0.0.1;
   }
 }
```

The GRPC service works fine and completes all requests but Nginx raises the following issue (I checked the error log):

> 2021/10/16 17:58:16 [error] 1137904#1137904: *2371 upstream sent frame for closed stream 1 while reading upstream, client: ******, server: mydomain.com, request: "POST /FileManagementService.Grpc.FileManagem>

Answer (score 0):

.proto

If the Method call equals

rpc Upload (**stream RequestFileUpload**) returns (**ResponseFileUpload**);

then. change  to

rpc Upload (**stream RequestFileUpload**) returns (**stream ResponseFileUpload**);

(  stream resuqet & normal return -> stream request & stream return )

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).